How to use FakeTimeProvider to test blocking code?
My code does actually poll until a certain state is reached, like this:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Time.Testing;

namespace TestFramework.Tests.Integration
{
    public class Tests
    {
        FakeTimeProvider timeProvider = new();

        [Test]
        public void WaitTillWithTimeout_WhenConditionAlwaysFalse_WillTimeoutAsDefined()
        {
            // Arrange
            AutomaticCalendar serviceUsingTimeprovider = new(timeProvider);
            var beforeCall = timeProvider.GetTimestamp();

            try
            {
                // Act
                WaitTillWithTimeout(serviceUsingTimeprovider, x => false, timeout: TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
                // TODO: advance the timeProvider to pass along all the days of the year; timeProvider.Advance(TimeSpan.FromDays(365)); does not work!
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                // Assert
                Assert.That(timeProvider.GetElapsedTime(beforeCall), Is.EqualTo(TimeSpan.FromDays(365)));
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void WaitTillWithTimeout_WhenConditionTrueWithin7Days_WillTimeoutWithin7Days()
        {
            // Arrange
            AutomaticCalendar serviceUsingTimeprovider = new(timeProvider);
            var beforeCall = timeProvider.GetTimestamp();

            // Act
            WaitTillWithTimeout(serviceUsingTimeprovider, x => x.DayOfWeek == "Friday", timeout: TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
            // TODO: advance the timeProvider to pass along all the days of the year; timeProvider.Advance(TimeSpan.FromDays(365)); does not work!

            // Assert
            Assert.That(timeProvider.GetElapsedTime(beforeCall), Is.LessThan(TimeSpan.FromDays(7)));
            // TODO Assert that the method does not hang forever
        }

        private void WaitTillWithTimeout(AutomaticCalendar testCalendar, Predicate<AutomaticCalendar> computation, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            var pollingPeriod = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);

            var start = timeProvider.GetTimestamp();
            Exception? lastException = null;
            bool result = false;
            while (timeProvider.GetElapsedTime(start) <= timeout)
            {
                try
                {
                    result = computation(testCalendar);
                }
                catch (System.Exception error)
                {
                    lastException = error;
                }

                if (result)
                {
                    return;
                }
                timeProvider.Delay(pollingPeriod).Wait();
            }

            if (!result)
            {
                throw new TimeoutException($"timeout after {timeout}", lastException);
            }
        }

        public class AutomaticCalendar
        {
            public string? DayOfWeek { get; private set; }

            internal AutomaticCalendar(TimeProvider timeProvider)
            {
                // everyhour update the day of the week
                timeProvider.CreateTimer(state => DayOfWeek = timeProvider.GetUtcNow().DayOfWeek.ToString(), null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
            }
         }
    }
}

I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.Time.Testing.FakeTimeProvider in my service and integration tests.
I want to verify in my integration tests that it does actually not take too little or too much time.
The solution direction is have chosen is to make use to TimeProvider to really influence the passage of time as it appears to my code.
I tried using TimeProvider.Advance(...) but then I have to execute this statement in parallel with WaitTillWithTimeout(...).
How to deal with this?
Seems I need something like
// increment the FakeTimeProvider slowly until 3 seconds are passed with increments of 100ms over a period of 1 sec
using(var advancer = TimeAdvancer(_timeprovider, advance:TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), increment:TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), realtime: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
{
   WaitTillWithTimeout(serviceUsingTimeprovider, x => false, timeout: TimeSpan.FromDays(365));           
}

        private static IDisposable TimeAdvancer(FakeTimeProvider timeProvider, TimeSpan advance, TimeSpan increment)
        {
            var advancerFunc = () =>
            {
                for (var time = TimeSpan.Zero; time < advance; time += increment)
                {
                    timeProvider.Advance(increment);
                }
            };

            var cancellationTokenSource = TimeProvider.System.CreateCancellationTokenSource(realtime.Value);
            Task.Run(advancerFunc, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

            return new MyDisposable(() => {
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            });
        }

But the above does not work, since the TimeAdvancer can be ready before the WaitTillWithTimeout has started.
Maybe someone has dealt with same problem?

What is S in S("#pwd") ?

S is a method that returns a reference to an element on an HTML page. The blocking wait is in the Should method. I will elaborate that method a bit more.

Can you please provide a full [mre] which can be run and reproduce the problem?

Added a reprex.

Are those unit or integration tests? The code says TestFramework.Tests.Integration but the tag on the question says unit-testing

Thanks, it can be used for both, so added the tag integration-testing too.
